# what is the wrong with this code"length indicator implementation"?

Tags: c++, implementation, indicator

this is an implementation of length indicator field 
but it hang and i think stuck at a loop and don't show any thing.

```
// readx22.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;


class Student
{
public:
 string id;
 size_t id_len;
 string first_name;
 size_t first_len;
 string last_name;
 size_t last_len;
 string phone;
 size_t phone_len;
 string grade;
 size_t grade_len;
 void read(fstream &ven);
 void print();
};
void Student::read(fstream &ven)
{
 size_t cnt;
 ven >> cnt;
 id_len=cnt;
    id.reserve( cnt );
    while ( -- cnt ) {
        id.push_back( ven.get() );
    }

 ven >> cnt;
 first_len=cnt;
    first_name.reserve( cnt );
    while ( -- cnt ) {
        first_name.push_back( ven.get() );
    }

 ven >> cnt;
 last_len=cnt;
    last_name.reserve( cnt );
    while ( -- cnt ) {
        last_name.push_back( ven.get() );
    }

 ven >> cnt;
 phone_len=cnt;
    phone.reserve( cnt );
    while ( -- cnt ) {
        phone.push_back( ven.get() );
    }

 ven >> cnt;
 grade_len=cnt;
    grade.reserve( cnt );
    while ( -- cnt ) {
        grade.push_back( ven.get() );
    }

}
void Student::print()
{
// string::iterator it;
 for ( int i=0 ; i<id_len; i++)
  cout << id[i];

}
int main()
{
 fstream in;
 in.open ("fee.txt", fstream::in);
 Student x;
 x.read(in);
 x.print();
 return 0;
}
```

thanks

Comment: you may want to write to the console all what comes in order to pinpoint the problem e.g. what 'cnt' contains. also show the code when you write the records because judging from how the class is declared one may think that length comes after the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should have used `cnt--` instead of `-- cnt` everywhere. The first zero-byte string will trigger an extremely large loop that eventually consumes all memory (except maybe on a 64-bit OS). Actually, don't even bother with this fix. Loop over `get()` is extremely inefficient, just call `read()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are seeing an infinite loop when you run this?

I'd be curious to know what **cnt** is before each loop.

Also, does your code actually make it to **x.print()**?

---

Also, this sounds like a great time to take out a debugger and run it on your code. If it is an infinite loop, a debugger will very quickly tell you where you are stuck.

Comment: yes,i see infinite loop

cnt reads how long the string is 
for example: 4wine cnt reads 4 and use it to read the string 
no i think the infinite loop exist in x.read()